# how to bind itemsource to combox which is in datagrid having again another itemsource

Tags: wpf, binding

This id my code..
how to bind itemsource to combox which is in datagrid having again another itemsource

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgData" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderBrush="Aqua" MinWidth="500" MinHeight="270" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedAccDtList}" Background="Transparent"  CanUserAddRows="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>                                           
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="SR.NO." Binding="{Binding SelectedAccDtList.InstCode}" />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn  Header="ACCESSORY_NAME" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SelectedAccList, Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedValuePath="ItemCode" DisplayMemberPath="ItemName" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ACCESSORY_SCOPE" Binding="{Binding AccScop}"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="ACCESSORY_TYPE" ItemsSource="{Binding AcccTyp}">
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: POst your viewmodel code

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you need to structure your data correctly. That means that you need to have a class for your data items and in that class, you need to have one collection property:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ClassItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>                                           
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding StringPropertyFromClass}" Header="SR.NO." />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionPropertyFromClass}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding DataItemPropertyFromClass, Mode=Two-Way}" Header="Items" />
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```